# String comparison with multiple words in PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison

I'm still working on my library database.

With PHP, how can I compare strings with multiple words in a different order, like `Gaius Julius Caesar` and `Caesar Gaius Julius` to see if they match? Commas, dashes, double spaces etc. will be removed before the comparison.

To place the strings into two arrays and to check with `in_array()` if every element of the first one is comprised in the second one could be a reasonable solution for a single couple of strings, but it seems a waste of CPU to check a list of over 5,000 names from a MariaDB table (5,000 × 5,000 = 25,000,000 of comparisons).

Suggestions?

Comment: *Suggestions?* for what?

Comment: You can use 2 foreach loops.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you doing like a spell check to see if the words are safe? or are you needing all words in both arrays to be identical in a different order. It will greatly change the algorithm.

Comment: @danielson317 - I need to see if there are names stored twice with a different form. The DB in use now is nothing more than a sort of huge Excel sheet, where all authors have to be retyped for every book, a waste of human resources and a big source of errors, and I want to replace that with a reference to a table containing all the authors. But of course I want to have them just once.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini - Sounds like this is a one time operation. Since you can flatten the authors and move them to a new table. Since it only needs to be done once as a migration operation then performance should not be a concern.

Comment: @danielson317 - Yes, the main table must be arranged once, but a check must anyway be done every time a new author is inserted. Having the data in the right order it is faster to check, and even to warn operators of existing entries with a simple Ajax.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini - I think I understand now. After migrating the user will still be adding new authors. The entire author name is in one field and the user may insert the name in different formats. In this case I would use an ajax autocomplete field and let the users intelligence take over. This will also help with misspelling and such. Similar to the way tags work here on stack overflow. Simply use a jquery autocomplete with a call to a like query %string% and let the user select the repeat author.

Comment: @danielson317 - There will be also a field for the "von" preposition, since many German names can be known with or without it (German telephone books sort users just under the surname), and for ancient religious authors, like "William of Baskerville" or "Adso of Melk", there will be another field for the place. As last resource, if the name can't be found into the main authors table, I'm thinking to make an alternate table extracting the "preferred" and "alternate" forms from the VIAF data. Here is a sample of the many forms an author can have: http://viaf.org/viaf/20795029/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$a = "Gaius Julius Caesar";
$b = "Caesar Gaius Julius Putin";
$ar1 = explode(' ', $a);
$ar2 = explode(' ', $b);
$ar3 = array_intersect($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($ar3);
```

Yields

```
Array ( [0] => Gaius [1] => Julius [2] => Caesar )
```

Too see if they match - just compare their `count()`

Comment: Probably better with `array_diff`.